# Confusion in understanding BCS ground state

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

Is there any absolute value BCS ground State?

What confuses me is that the number of particles is not fixed, so when we add a BCS pair to the ground state, it will further decrease the ground state energy. I am assuming that BCS pair has negative energy.

Any comments on this will be useful.

Comment: The BCS state is indeed an eigenstate of the pair-annihilation operator, that's the beauty of it. Therefore the energy stays the same when adding/removing particles. I don't know why you are "assuming that BCS pair has negative energy", that's clearly not the case for this state. You may also want to read up about coherent states, for instance https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.62.867

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any absolute value BCS ground State?

Yes.

In any metal, electrons occupy the allowed states up to the Fermi energy $E_F$. The Fermi energy is *defined* to be highest occupied energy. The Fermi surface is the surface separating occupied and unoccupied states (valence and conduction band).

The energy in both a normal metal and a superconductor is just the sum of the energies of all the electrons.

In a superconductor, the electrons in the vicinity of the Fermi surface form Cooper pairs (in the presence of an attractive interaction, e.g. electron-phonon). Being a bound state, this has a *lower* energy than the two free electrons. So when counting the energy for a superconductor, sum the energies of all the electrons (except the ones forming pairs), then add the energy of the Cooper pairs. The energy will be a be lower than in the metal case (where you count all electrons and there are not Cooper pairs).

NB: the electrons that form Cooper pairs are already in the vicinity of the Fermi level i.e. they are already the electrons that conduct electricity in normal metals. But if they form Cooper pairs, the energy is lowered and hence a gap opens. The next excited states are now a gap $\Delta$ away, instead of being immediately contiguous in a continuum like in the normal metal stage. This is why the electrons in the Cooper pairs cannot scatter into these excited states because of temperature or defects (i.e. the source of resistance in metals), unless a lot of energy is supplied (and superconductivity is destroyed).

> the number of particles is not fixed

Sure the BCS wavefunction is a coherent state and hence not an eigenstate of the number operator. But you still have lepton number conservation. The *total* number of electrons is conserved. I would guess that the number uncertainty in the BCS wavefunction is exactly and opposite the number uncertainty in the electrons not participating in the superconducting state (i.e. the ones far away from the Fermi level), so that the net uncertainty is zero.

> we add a BCS pair to the ground state

You don't add anything.

Given an attractive interaction between electrons, the electrons naturally form these pairs in order to seek an energetically favourable, lower energy state.

You can ask: what if I add an electron? All the states below the Fermi energy are, by definition, occupied, so the electron will sit near the Fermi level. It will increase the energy of the whole system since you have to count this one as well in your energy sum. Being alone, it cannot form a Cooper pair. You can then add another electron, and this may now form a Cooper pair with the other one. The total energy is now roughly (2$\times$Fermi energies - 1$\times$Cooper binding energy) higher than before adding the two electrons.

> it will further decrease the ground state energy

I hope the last point also answers this question. 
 You don't need reach zero energy. In order to be energetically favourable, your superconducting state just needs to have a *lower* energy than that of the normal metal. It doesn't matter how many electrons you have far away from the Fermi level (which give you a higher total energy) -- these electrons don't participate in the conduction anyway.

> I am assuming that BCS pair has negative energy.

As said before, no. Adding two electrons will raise the total energy by roughly (2$\times$Fermi energies - 1$\times$Cooper binding energy).

It does not matter that the whole energy is going up. It matters that there is a gap between the Cooper pair electrons (the one that are around the Fermi level and hence conducting electricity) and the next available states. This gap grows with decreasing temperature, so it becomes ever more difficult to make the conducting 'electrons' reach these stats, which would mean they would be involved in scattering mechanisms (i.e. the metal displays resistance). Instead, the Cooper electrons just keep doing what they were doing unaffected: if they had an initial velocity, e.g. given by exposing the system to a voltage for some time, they will keep it.

Comment: `the number of particles is not fixed` -- They are indeed not fixed. BCS theory is formulated in the grand canonical ensemble with a fixed chemical potential, which fixes a average value of the number of electron, but there are fluctuations.